# Why is this regular expression not working for redirection?

Tags: regex, redirect

I'm trying to set up a wildcard redirect in Wordpress using the Redirection plugin, that supports regular expression.

I have a bunch of urls that look like this:

- www.example.com/details.php?Pin=1234
- www.example.com/details.php?Pin=5678

That I want to have redirected to the following format:

- www.example.com/readers/1234/
- www.example.com/readers/5678/

I have a source and a target field to enter redirection entries, and I currently have it set as such:

```
Source: /details.php?Pin=(.*)
Target: /readers/$1/
```

Which I believe is the correct expressions to be using, for a simple wildcard. But no redirection is happening. I'm not too clued up on regular expression, so would anyone be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong with the expressions?

Comment: What's the regex flavor? If it's JS-based you'll have to escape the `/` -> `\/`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the regex flavour is to be honest, the plugin that I'm using is located at https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/. I'll try escaping the slashes and see if that kicks in.

Comment: @ClasG No, escaping the slashes didn't seem to make any improvement.

Comment: He he... Now I see it - it's the `?` that need to be escaped. `Source: /details.php\?Pin=(.*)`. In it's present form it makes the last `p` in `php` optional.

Comment: That's got it, thanks for that. I was getting really confused there thinking I'm using the conditions correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `?`  that need to be escaped.

```
Source: /details.php\?Pin=(.*)
```

In it's present form it makes the last `p` in `php` optional.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
\/details.php\?Pin=(\d+)
/readers/$1/
```

Tested in notepad++.